# Recursive method containing for loop return statement issue

Tags: java, recursion, for-loop, return

This is for a homework assignment. The homework is not on recursion it is on tree structures. I have nearly finished the assignment, but my recursive method for moving back up a tree breaks. The tree structure is given by the class below:

```
package lab12;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Dog implements Serializable{

    public Dog[] children;
    public String name;

    public Dog(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return name;
    }

}
```

I'm quite certain the reason is the return null; statement in combination with my for loop. The for loop iterates over a node that doesn't contain any children and as a result returns null. This ends the method and passes back null to my program which gives me null pointer exceptions.

I can't remove the return null statement or it won't compile, even though it will 100% return using the for loop.

```
public Dog findParent(Dog root, String name)
{
    String top = "Spot";
    if(top.equals(name))
    {
        System.out.println("No further records");
        System.out.println("Goodbye.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    for(int i = 0; root.children != null && i < root.children.length; i++)
    {
        if(root.children[i].name.equals(name))
        {
            return root;
        }
        else
        {
            return findParent(root.children[i], name);
        }
    }
    return null; //Compiler still requires a return here.
}
```

I feel like this has to be a common problem with using for loops in non-void recursive methods. Is there a way to make the compiler happy and yet not have the extra return null statement?

Comment: When posting, please make sure to _ask a question_ on a problem. StackOverflow is not he to debug your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code must not work. Because both if and else clauses will return. That causes the loop only do index 0. You should change your code like the following:

```
public Dog findParent(Dog root, String name)
{
    String top = "Spot";
    if(top.equals(name))
    {
        System.out.println("No further records");
        System.out.println("Goodbye.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    for(int i = 0; root.children != null && i < root.children.length; i++)
    {
        if(root.children[i].name.equals(name))
        {
            return root;
        }
        else
        {
            Dog parent = findParent(root.children[i], name);
            if (parent != null) 
                 return parent;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now, you can see that the last "return null" is necessary.

In most of case, compiler is smart. If it gives your warnings, you should consider what's error with your code instead just cheat compiler to avoid warning.

Comment: This doesn't break, but it also doesn't find the parent. I used root.children[i] to look into the current node's children and see if they were equal to the name of the node I am trying to find the parent of. Using root.name.equals(name) makes it find where the nodes name is equal to the name of the node I am trying to find parents for. Once you've gone down the tree that far you can't move back up.

Comment: Did you try my code on your computer? I showed you right way to do recursively search.

Comment: Yes I tried your code. Unfortunately it sets the node to the same node that I am trying to find the parent of. If you run it you get the same node over and over.

Comment: And you're right, your code is great for doing a recursive search. I already have code that can do that. I'm trying to write code that can find the parent node to a node I input.

Comment: OK, I didn't understand your real question, and it seems you have updated your question, and stated more clearly. I also updated my answer.

Comment: I actually on a whim tried using your if(ret!=null) statement and got it to work before I saw your edit. Looking at your edit it is exactly what I ended up with as working code. Thank you very much!

Comment: To anyone having problems with return statements in recursive methods that use for loops, Evan Li gave the correct answer! Please up vote him and not the other post which ignores the for loop. I would upvote, but I only have 11 rep so far, I'll come back and vote when I have more.

Comment: Instead upvote, maybe you can accept the answer by clicking the correct sign. Accepting answer might not require your reputation.

Answer (score 2):

Without understanding this problem entirely, I see no reason for the "return null" statement to never execute.  Perhaps you else statement should be:

```
return findParent(root.children[i], name);
```

This return will ensure that once the "parent" is found its value will be returned.

Comment: How do I do this in the context of a for loop? I edited my code above to return findParent(root.children[i], name); and got rid of my else statement so now it's just a for loop. The compiler still requires the extra return null statement on the end.